# How do I reassign a bash array element

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash and trying to set the following:

```
readarray -t countries

for key in ${!countries[@]}
do
  if [[ "${countries[$key]}" =~ ^[A-Z]* ]]
  then
    echo "countries[$key]"= $(echo "${countries[$key]}" | tr '[A-Z]' '.')
  else
    echo $value
  fi
done
```

When I run the above I get:

```
countries[0]= .amibia
countries[1]= .auru
countries[2]= .epal
countries[3]= .etherlands
```

Not what I was expecting. I want the actual element updated. But if I remove the echo from the line:

```
echo "countries[$key]"= $(echo "${countries[$key]}" | tr '[A-Z]' '.')
```

so:

```
"countries[$key]"= $(echo "${countries[$key]}" | tr '[A-Z]' '.')
```

I get:

```
Solution.sh: line 7: countries[0]=: command not found
Solution.sh: line 7: countries[1]=: command not found
Solution.sh: line 7: countries[2]=: command not found
Solution.sh: line 7: countries[3]=: command not found
```

Additionally if I change the line to:

```
countries[$key]= $(echo "${countries[$key]}" | tr '[A-Z]' '.')
```

I get:

```
Solution.sh: line 7: `countries[$key]': not a valid identifier
Solution.sh: line 7: .amibia: command not found
Solution.sh: line 7: `countries[$key]': not a valid identifier
Solution.sh: line 7: .auru: command not found
Solution.sh: line 7: `countries[$key]': not a valid identifier
Solution.sh: line 7: .epal: command not found
Solution.sh: line 7: `countries[$key]': not a valid identifier
Solution.sh: line 7: .etherlands: command not found
```

I'm out of ideas on how to move forward. Any thoughts on a resolution?

Comment: Try running your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It'll catch and help with a lot of syntax issues.

Comment: Remove the space after `=`

Comment: The quotes need to be removed as well as the space: `countries[$key]=$(echo "${countries[$key]}" | tr 'A-Z' '.')`.

Comment: WOW, I can't believe that a space did that. So much cautiousness in Bash, it's making me very nervous. It's a very strange language and has peculiarities . Thank you, I've spent an hour on trying different things.

Comment: Indeed, bash can be rather picky about whitespace. In a similar vein, square brackets are another trap. Don't condense `if [[ $foo == bar ]]` to `if [[$foo==bar]]`. The spaces are required.

Comment: @Dan Pretty much every quirk in `bash` and other POSIX-style shell can be explained by the fact that at its core, its purpose is to execute commands with space-separated arguments, and that very few characters are "special". `foo= bar` is just a command named `foo=` with `bar` as its argument; `foo =bar` is `foo` with argument `=bar`; `foo\=bar` is a command named `foo=bar`. (The `=` is escaped to prevent interpretation as an assignment.

Comment: @chepner hem, `foo= bar` will assign *nothing* to variable `$foo` in new *environment* for running command `bar`. (running on my host, this show: *`bash: bar: command not found`*)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub :facepalm: